# MongoDB - Can't canonicalize query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to run mapreduce on a collection using the C# driver (1.9.0) and a scope variable.
I use the following code:

```
var map = @"function() {
    emit(this._id, foo); 
};";

var reduce = @"function(key, values) { 
    return values; 
};";

var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
options.SetScope(new ScopeDocument("foo", "foo"));
```

When I use this code I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' occurred
>   in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Command 'mapreduce' failed: exception: Can't
>   canonicalize query {} (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: Can't
>   canonicalize query {}", "code" : 17238, "ok" : 0.0 })

If I remove the scope variable like below it works:

```
var map = @"function() {
    //emit(this._id, foo); 
    emit(this._id, 1); 
};";

var reduce = @"function(key, values) { 
    return values; 
};";

var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
//options.SetScope(new ScopeDocument("foo", "foo"));
```

Does anyone know that's wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of foo? Is it calculated based on some of the documents fields?

Comment: Does it need a setFinalize when applying a scope?

Comment: @Sebastian  Foo is just a variable I want to use in my map function to filter the result.

Comment: @WillShaver how do you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solotion. It turns out I have to use the BsonJavaScriptWithScope instead of SetScope.

```
var map = @"function() {
    emit(this._id, foo); 
};";

var reduce = @"function(key, values) { 
    return values; 
};";

var scope = new BsonDocument("foo", "foo");

var args = new MapReduceArgs()
{
    MapFunction = new BsonJavaScriptWithScope(map, scope),
    ReduceFunction = new BsonJavaScript(reduce),
    OutputMode = MapReduceOutputMode.Inline
};  

var results = collection.MapReduce(args).GetResults();
```

Comment: It would be nice if you updated the sample to show how to use multiple values, also "foo" for both key and value is a bit confusing. E.g., : var scope = new BsonDocument { { "var1", "value1" }, { "var2", "value2" } };